# How to create a method that retrieves a sublist containing elements of a specific class T?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following function

```
public <T> T getItemsByType(){
    T[] retarr = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
        if(items.get(i).get instanceof T){

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I need my function to search in a list of `items` for instances of type T and then return an array of T.

Of course, this would've been great if worked but the problem is that:

`Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter T. Use its erasure Object instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime`

What should I do to obtain the same effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `Class<T> clazz` as argument to your method, then use it to check if the element can be assignable to that class by using [`Class#isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
public <T> T getItemsByType(Class<T> clazz) {
    T[] retarr = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
        if(clazz.isInstance(items.get(i))){
            //do your logic here...
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Some recomendations:

- It would be better returning a `List<T>` or `Collection<T>` instead of returning a single `T` element.
- Avoid returning `null`, so you don't have to do `null`-defensive programming.
- Use an iterator or an enhanced `for` loop to traverse through all the elements in your list.

So, a better implementation would be:

```
public <T> List<T> getItemsByType(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> theList = new ArrayList<T>();
    //using Object since you never specified which type of elements holds this list
    for (Object o : items) {
        if(clazz.isInstance(o)) {
            //do your logic here...
            theList.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }
    }
    return theList;
}
```

Comment: How should I do the call of the function?

Comment: Got it: `getItemsByType(WebsiteUrl.class);`

Comment: Possibly necessary: `theList.add(clazz.cast(o))`.